# Syntax error near unexpected token "elif" in bash

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

Here's my code to display some dialogs.

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(zenity  --list --text="Choose action" --column= --hide-header "Hidden Files" "Desktop")
if [ $output = "Hidden Files"]
    then
        output2=$(zenity  --list --text="Do what?" --column= --hide-header "Show" "Hide")
        if [ $output2 = "Show"]
            then
                echo showing files
            else
                echo hiding files
elif [ $output = "Desktop"];then
        output3=$(zenity  --list --text="Do what?" --column= --hide-header "Show" "Hide")
        if [ $output2 = "Show"]
            then
                echo showing files
            else
                echo hiding files
    else
        exit
fi
```

I get this error after the first dialog:

```
systool.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
systool.sh: line 12: `elif [ $output = "Desktop"];then'
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close both of your inner if-else statements with a `fi`.

For example:

```
    if [ $output2 = "Show"]
        then
            echo showing files
        else
            echo hiding files
    fi
```

You also need a space before the closing `]` in your if conditions. For example:

```
    if [ $output2 = "Show" ]
```

Comment: got a new problem... `systool.sh: line 14: [: =: unary operator expected`

Comment: The if-statement under "Desktop" is referring to the wrong variable. It should be output3, not output2. Change to: `if [ $output3 = "Show" ]`

Comment: Also, you should always double-quote your variable expansions (unless there's a specific reason not to). For example, the first `if` statement should be: `if [ "$output" = "Hidden Files" ]` -- otherwise if $output is `Hidden Files`, the test command will see that as two strings instead of one, and get very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `if`s have no corresponding `fi`s.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `fi` after both `echo hiding files`